# Simple permissions in a single field for rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want add any kind of permissions for my rails models just including one module to the model and defining metadata in one database field. How i can do this?

For example:

```
Folder < AR::B
  @permissions_list = [:is_private, :public_on_negotioation]
  @permissions_field = :perms
  include Permissions
end

module Permissions
  "...?"
end
```

i want to have methods "is_private?", "is_private", "is_private=" for all items in a @permissions_list variable.

So i can use model in this way:

```
f = Folder.new
f.is_private = true
f.public_on_negotioation = false
f.save
f.reload
f.is_private?
=> true
f.public_on_negotioation?
=> false
```

so i wrote next Module:

```
module Permissions
  def self.included(mod)
    permissions_list = mod.instance_variable_get(:@permissions_list)
    permissions_list.each_with_index do |permission, index|
      define_method permission.to_sym do
        perms_bits[index] == '1'
      end
    alias_method (permission.to_s << "?").to_sym, permission.to_sym
    end
  end

def perms_bits
  send(self.class.instance_variable_get(:@permissions_field)).to_i.to_s(2).reverse
end

  def set_permission(name, weight, options)
    permissions_field = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@permissions_field)
    if options[name]
      self.send("#{permissions_field}=", self.send(permissions_field).to_i + weight.to_i)      unless send(name)
    elsif options.has_key?("#{name}_off")
      self.send("#{permissions_field}=", self.send(permissions_field).to_i - weight.to_i)      if send(name)
    end
  end

  def update_perms(options)
    permissions_list = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@permissions_list)
    permissions_list.each_with_index do |permission, index|
      set_permission(permission.to_sym, 2**index, options)
    end
    save
  end
end
```

some improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the answer from mdesantis. The way you can wrap up the permissions code for reuse could be something like this (untested):

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Permissions
end

PERMISSIONS_STRUCT = Struct.new(:is_private, :public_on_negotiation)

module Permissions
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.class_eval do
      serialize :permissions, PERMISSIONS_STRUCT
    end
    klass.include(InstanceMethods)
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def is_private?
      permissions.is_private
    end

    def is_private=(is_private)
      permissions.is_private = is_private
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ActiveRecord::serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize):

```
Folder < AR::B
  # Must be costant, otherwise Rails will raise an
  # ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch
  PERMISSIONS_STRUCT = Struct.new(:is_private, :public_on_negotiation)

  serialize :permissions, PERMISSIONS_STRUCT

  def is_private?
    permissions.is_private
  end

  def is_private=(is_private)
    permissions.is_private = is_private
  end

  # The same for public_on_negotiation
end

f = Folder.new
f.is_private = true
f.save
f.reload
f.is_private?
=> true
```

If you need to dynamically define accessor methods:

```
Folder < AR::B
  [:is_private, :public_on_negotiation].each do |action|
    define_method("#{action}?") do
      permissions.send action
    end
  end
  # And so on for "#{action}=", ...
end
```

And remember: **refactoring is up to you!** :-)

Comment: i just want include one module to model and get all functionality, but not write dozens of code for each permission, because may be a lot of them. But any way thanks.

Comment: My answer is a proof of concept about what you requested; the methods problem is another question, solvable using metaprogramming. Check f.e. [this](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/2-metaprogramming-ruby/chapters/25-dynamic-methods/lessons/72-define-method#magic_block-3914)